# Should visa questions be tagged with [country] or [city]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I came across a question today, about a user asking if Indian citizens need a transit visa for Thailand (Bangkok).

The questions revisions can be viewed [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/147170/revisions). It was tagged with all the necessary visa and citizenship tags. It was also tagged with Thailand and Bangkok.

I removed the Bangkok tag, just leaving the Thailand tag and all the other tags. The OP then replaced the Thailand tag with the Bangkok tag.

I rolled it back and left a comment:

> This question is about Thailand in general, so it needs a Thailand tag, not a Bangkok one

In my opinion this only needs a Thailand tag. Should we assume this for all questions.

In general:

## A user might only be travelling to a different city

Say a similar question is asked about an Indian citizen needing a transit visa for another city in Thailand. They search Thailand, but as it isn’t tagged they don’t see that question.

## Less duplicates

As mentioned above, less duplicates will be asked.

## When will a country have visa rules varying by city?

In general, I don’t see a country having different visa rules per city (apart from some disputed territories)

**Are we all in consensus to tag visa question by country not by city?**

If you have objections please leave an answer with your view.

Comment: Regular users rarely use tags to search. Instead they use Google which is very good at identifying relevant questions. Remember that 90% of our traffic comes from search engines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are possibly just a handful of cases in which the visa policy depends on the city and/or on the airport to which one is travelling. One that I am aware of is the [Transit WithOut Visa policy of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Visa-free_transit), which applies some restrictions if one travels through certain airports. In these cases it might make sense to have a city-/airport-specific tag for the question. Other than these cases, I would stick to country tags.